# where to include script files so that it works for every blade file in laravel5.5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.5

I created a master layout blade file and included in every view file. I have also mentioned the stylesheets in that file. The css is working fine but if I include script file in head section of master layout file, the scripts does not work in view files. Why is that?

If i mention script files in view files, then the script starts working. Where should I include my script files so that it don't I have to include it in every view file.?

I have included code to in clude script in my layout file(included in every view file). Below is the image:-
[image]

And, further is the script included in blade file.

```
@push('script-head')

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   jQuery("#client_list").on("click",function()
   {
       alert("hello");
   }
}
</script>
@endpush
```

And I am getting error:-

```
client-database:51 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: script file include in header or footer..

Comment: you can add that in your main blade file, usually its the `layouts/app.blade.php`

Comment: any js,css in the master layout should be available to the child layout

Comment: your js files should be placed before the </body> tag, but if it is possible, let us see your code, maybe you have a problem with closing the section.

Answer (score 0):

Include js file in your footer and use footer in your master layout then use your master layout in every pages.